# Block Ping from server using iptables based on packet count

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, icmp

I am trying to block icmp pings from a server if the packet count is greater than 2 per second (packet count reduced for testing).
I tried these 2 rules separately but they don't seem to help:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 2 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT --match limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 2
```

wht's wrong with these rules ?

I am pinging form another server using below command but the ping continues to get replies -

```
ping -n -i 0.2 192.168.2.86
```

also when I check iptables -nvL output - the packet count for the rule is not increasing ...

Machine used is centos 6.8

Some Progress:
I added a default drop rule at the end of table:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp -j DROP
```

and then adding this rule dropped pings that exceeded the limit

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 2/second -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "icmprule1"
```

still not able to block the server completely.

Comment: wild guess: does the packet match an earlier rule?

Comment: i have done a `iptables -F` before testing any of these rules seperately

Comment: For clarification: you want to completely block ICMP from a server which exceeds (in this example) 2/s, or do you want to block _everything_ from this server if ICMP exceeds 2/s or do you want to block ICMP if it exceeds 2/s and accept the rest?

Comment: just want to block icmp for now if icmp limit exceeds 2/s .. 

if you can giv a solution to block all requests for ip exceeding 2/s limit then this will be a bonus answer since this is what my final plan is. (i.e FINAL PLAN : to block all request from and ip for an hr if the request count exceeds 2/s using iptables.). but for now icmp blocking shud suffice as I can implement the latter.

Comment: take a look at my update below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes, adding a secondary ICMPSCAN chain (and putting the jump rule in first position of INPUT chain):

```
iptables -N ICMPSCAN
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ICMPSCAN 
iptables -A ICMPSCAN -m recent --set --name badicmp --rsource 
iptables -A ICMPSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 2 --name badicmp --rsource -j DROP
```

Note: both set/update rules could be set instead in INPUT without the secondary, but I prefer to put such rules in  distinct chains.

Note2: an additional rule after --set could be added to log the event...

## dynamic blacklisting:

Now, to add a permanent dynamic blacklist based on recent hitcount trigger, we can take advantage of ipset feature. ipset is available for centos 6.x , and iptables is ipset aware, but you may need to install it first.

Here the iptables/ipset rules to match your need:

```
iptables -F ICMPSCAN
iptables -N ICMPSCAN
ipset -N banned_hosts iphash
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ICMPSCAN 
iptables -A ICMPSCAN -m recent --set --name badicmp --rsource 
iptables -A ICMPSCAN -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 2 --name badicmp --rsource -j SET --add-set banned_hosts src
iptables -A ICMPSCAN -m set --set banned_hosts src -j DROP
```

You can list the current contents of banned list using ipset list, for example:

```
# ipset list banned_hosts
Name: banned_hosts
Type: hash:ip
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 8284
References: 2
Members:
192.168.122.1
```

and manage the set list, for example to remove an ip address like:

```
# ipset del banned_hosts 192.168.122.1
```

See also this page: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/advanced-firewall-configurations-ipset

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted, its stops the icmp requests, though if I rerun the ping command at normal request rate the ping starts again. Is there a way iptables can block the pings permanently (or maybe add to a blacklist) for this server ? 
Upvoting your answer for now and i'll wait/work on a permanent block solution. If things can't go that way, i'll accept your answer and add logging to the rules and then maybe write a script to parse the logs and block the ip permanently.

Comment: updated my answer to match this.

Comment: You may combine logging with fail2ban to achieve a long-term blocking.

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT!! @tonioc tried and tested.. Thankyou